error TS2307: Cannot find module '@adminjs/mongoose' or its corresponding type declarations. Error al integrar base de datos mongoose AdminJS
Buen día, estoy tratando de integrar una base de datos de mongoose a mi proyecto de AdminJS con express.js, he importado todos los paquetes, pero cuando corro el servidor me aparece que no se puede encontrar el módulo @adminjs/mongoose, no sé si sea un error de compatibilidad, pero ya estuve investigando y desinstalandolo e instalandolo de nuevo varias veces y sigue presentando el mismo error, si alguien pudiera ayudarme a encontrar la solución se lo agradecería demasiado. Adjunto el código de mi proyecto y los mensajes de error:
Este es el archivo principal app.js:
(El link de la mongoose está en un archivo .env)


import express from 'express';
import AdminJS from 'adminjs';
import AdminJSExpress from '@adminjs/express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import * as AdminJSMongoose from '@adminjs/mongoose';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { PersonModel } from './models/personModel.js';
dotenv.config();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

AdminJS.registerAdapter({ 
    Resource: AdminJSMongoose.Resource,
    Database: AdminJSMongoose.Database,
});

const start = async (): Promise<void> => {
  const app = express();

  await mongoose.connect(`${process.env.MONGO_URL}`);

  const admin = new AdminJS({
    resources: [
      {
        resource: PersonModel
      }
    ]
  });

  const adminRouter = AdminJSExpress.buildRouter(admin);

  app.use(admin.options.rootPath, adminRouter);

  console.log(`Iniciando servidor en el puerto ${port}`);
  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`AdminJS available at http://localhost:${port}${admin.options.rootPath}`);
  });
};

start();



Este es el archivo package.json que muestra los paquetes instalados:


{
  "name": "admin_wellfit",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "admin for wellfit project",
  "main": "./app.ts",
  "author": "OF",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^5.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "tslib": "^2.7.0",
    "typescript": "^5.6.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@adminjs/express": "^6.1.0",
    "@adminjs/mongoose": "^3.0.1",
    "adminjs": "^7.8.13",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "express": "^4.21.0",
    "express-formidable": "^1.2.0",
    "express-session": "^1.18.0",
    "mongoose": "^8.6.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "ts-node app.ts"
  }
}



Y este es el mensaje de error que me aparece al correr el servidor:


Alguna razón para no usar una versión actualizada de @adminjs/mongoose? La versión de adminjs que tienes es lo suficientemente actualizada como para que utilices la última versión del adaptador de Mongoose. Por cierto mongoose no es una Base de Datos, es un ODM (Object Data Modeling) para MongoDB (MongoDB sí es una Base de Datos)

Logré solucionarlo, eran problemas de compatibilidad con @adminjs/mongoose, tuve que actualizar la versión "module": a "Node16" para que fuera compatible en el archivo tsconfig.json

Logré solucionarlo, eran problemas de compatibilidad con @adminjs/mongoose, tuve que actualizar la versión "module": "Node16", para que fuera compatible en el archivo tsconfig.json


{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "Node16",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "moduleResolution": "node16",
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}



